# Axios GET, update Image Url vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

After calling Axios get method, my webpage receives a response of some image URL, but I cannot update/refresh/re-render the image alone without re-render the entire page. Can anyone help me with this problem? Examples would be greatly appreciated.

this is my code

```
<template>
img class="ig-img" src="arrayInstagramRequest[0]" alt="image">
</template>

  data: function () {
return {
  arrayInstagramRequest: [],
  convertedArrayInstagram: [],
  id: 0
}
  },

httpGetIstagramImage: function () {
  axios.get(configFile.basic_url + '/instagram_content/get_all').then((response) => {
    while (response.data.result[this.id] != null) {
      this.arrayInstagramRequest.push(response.data.result[this.id].instagram_url)
      this.id += 1
    }
    console.log(this.id)
    console.log(this.arrayInstagramRequest[0])
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  })
}
```

Comment: Could you add the <template> part of your component, and when is your 'httpGetIstagramImage' called?

Comment: yes i had add it on the first line of the code

Comment: could you please include `data` aswell?

Comment: added sir @majurageerthan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, You missed `:` in src

change `src` into `:src`

like below code, change this

```
<img class="ig-img" src="arrayInstagramRequest[0]" alt="image">
```

into this

```
<img class="ig-img" :src="arrayInstagramRequest[0]" alt="image">
```

Comment: no need sir bro, It was sad the initial solution didn't work, I gave another solution. Could you try it bro?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: `template` will be like

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img alt="Instagram Image" :src="arrayInstagramRequest[0]" width="25%" />
  </div>
</template>
```

Step 2: Instead of `axios` response i mocked the response in `dummyResponse` data object and the data will be below,

```
data() {
return {
  arrayInstagramRequest: [],
  convertedArrayInstagram: [],
  id: 0,
  dummyResponse: [
    {
      id: 0,
      Name: "Spec_0",
      Image: "https://www.encodedna.com/images/theme/jQuery.png",
    },

    {
      id: 1,
      Name: "Spec_1",
      Image: "https://www.encodedna.com/images/theme/json.png",
    },

    {
      id: 2,
      Name: "Spec_2",
      Image: "https://www.encodedna.com/images/theme/angularjs.png",
    },
  ],
};
},
```

Step 3: `httpGetIstagramImage` instead of getting the response from `axios` i am fetching from `dummyResponse` and binding to the image object.

```
methods: {
httpGetIstagramImage: function () {
  // axios
  //   .get("configFile.basic_url/instagram_content/get_all")
  //   .then((response) => {
  //     while (response.data.result[this.id] != null) {
  //       this.arrayInstagramRequest.push(
  //         response.data.result[this.id].instagram_url
  //       );
  //       this.id += 1;
  //     }
  //     console.log(this.id);
  //     console.log(this.arrayInstagramRequest[0]);
  //   })
  //   .catch((error) => {
  //     console.log(error);
  //   });
  if (this.dummyResponse) {
    this.dummyResponse.filter(function (e) {
      if (e.id === this.id) {
        this.arrayInstagramRequest.push(e.Image);
      }
      return e.id === this.id;
    }, this);
  }
},
},
```

Step 4: OnCreate method i am calling the function `httpGetIstagramImage`

```
created() {
  this.httpGetIstagramImage();
},
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-cloud-9vxrx)

Comment: i dont understandany of this sir

Comment: @someone_that_needHelp In axios api call you will get array of json response. Instead of `axios` call i just created this example with `dummyResponse` object. Do you want to display all the instagram pictures which you got from api response?

Comment: @someone_that_needHelp do you wants to display all the images which you got the response from `axios` response?

Comment: yes i want to display all the image that i got from the api, i already print the array member on console and i got an url

Comment: @someone_that_needHelp in change `axios` method like below `axios.get("configFile.basic_url/instagram_content/get_all")
.then((response) => {
  if (response) {
    this.arrayInstagramRequest = response.data.result
  }
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
}); ` and html template will be like `<div v-for="(res,$index) in arrayInstagramRequest" :key="$index">
  <img alt="Instagram Image" :src="res.Image" width="25%" />
</div>`

Comment: @someone_that_needHelp I updated my demo link too. You have to bind the `axis` response and display the `v-for` like mentioned in the demo link https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-cloud-9vxrx

Comment: thank you for you hard work sir but i have my own template all i want to know is how do i update my image src using  ur that i got from this variable arrayInstagramRequest[0] , because my   <img> not showing any picture, but. i already console.log(arrayInstagramRequest[0]) and i got the image url

Comment: @someone_that_needHelp can you provide your `axios` response. So that I will guide you how to display.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230128/discussion-between-jebasuthan-and-someone-that-needhelp).

Comment: @someone_that_needHelp your html template will be like `<img v-for="(res, $index) in arrayInstagramRequest" :key="$index" alt="Instagram Image" :src="res.Image" width="25%" />`

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the link it self and i need to ad ":" before. my src guys, thankyou for helping me